# I have an error when I import the data into postgresql from csv file with `sequel`

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am trying to import the data into postgresql from csv files as follows.

```
csv = CSV.open(path, { col_sep: ',', headers: :first_row })

MatchDB.db.copy_into(:property,
  data: csv,
  format: :csv
)
```

But I got an error like this.

```
TypeError: wrong argument type CSV::Row (expected String)
```

Anyone knows how can I fix that?

Comment: Would you please link a documentation on `MatchDB`?

Comment: It is just connect to DB.def self.db
    @@db ||= Sequel.connect(
            adapter: 'postgres',
            database: 'matches',
            user: 'master',
            host: 'localhost',
            password: '123456'
          )
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might see in [`Sequel`’s tests](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/90410ff39584cf9c8cb9cebcacb07664360d5b6e/spec/adapters/postgres_spec.rb#L1753), the [`Database#copy_into`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/1e9137167faade311f2ee255aba775beecd26cd5/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb#L390) method expects a string with columns separated by commas and rows separated by line separator `\n`.

You are trying to pass a ruby internal `CSV` representation, which is [generally speaking kinda] an array of arrays. I am not a guru in ruby `CSV`, but to make a proper string out of it, one might use:

```
csv.map { |row| row.join ',' }.join "\n"
```

The summing up:

```
csv = CSV.open(path, { col_sep: ',', headers: :first_row })

MatchDB.db.copy_into(:property,
  data: csv.map { |row| row.join ',' }.join "\n",
  format: :csv
)
```